# Secondary AD DC With Fail over

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, failover

Situation:

I have a AD DC authenticating all the users now and serve as the DNS as well.

Problem:

After reading through [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2015/03/04/step-by-step-setting-up-active-directory-sites-subnets-amp-site-links.aspx), I am wondering how do I set up another AD DC and configure the site and services when the IP address of both server is going to be in the same network?

I am assuming that I will have to DCpromp the 2nd DC and set up the DNS services first, how will I know if DNS will be synced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another one detailed step-by-step instruction on how to add second domain controller to existing site (in case if both domain controllers are in the same physical location)

Server 2008 R2: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733027(v=ws.10).aspx

Server 2012 R2: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20098.setting-up-additional-active-directory-domain-controller-with-windows-server-2012.aspx

Comment: First of all,  I would like to apologize for the late response.  I had just got out of micro disectomy surgery.  The guide looks promising and even though it I am using  Windows 2008, I am sure that running test on VMs will help me.  Thanks for the direction pointed to me. Cheers mate.

Comment: Hi Guang, I've updated my answer with links to both versions

Comment: Hi Sergey!  Tested on VM with your links and it works. I will be implementing it to the production env! thanks!

Comment: Hi Guang, glad to hear!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the first paragraph of that article:

> In  an Active Directory infrastructure setup, the Domain represents the logical topology while **Sites and Subnets represent the physical topology**.

You do not need a second site for a secondary domain controller, if that DC is at the same location and in the same network.

> I am assuming that I will have to DCpromp the 2nd DC and set up the DNS services first, how will I know if DNS will be synced?

Just use the wizard to add another domain controller to the domain. You do not need to do anything else, because by default DNS is Active-Directory integrated and will sync with it using FRS (default) or DFSR (recommended).

(Unless you changed that …)